# System.InvalidOperationException: 'There is no ViewData item of type 'IEnumerable<SelectListItem>' that has the key 'DDlist'.'

Tags: c#, mvc, asp, net

En la view "Create" de mi proyecto me arroja el DropDownList los Tipos de productos que tengo guardados en la base de datos, pero al guardar el producto, no lo hace y no se porque, me arroja el error:

> System.InvalidOperationException: 'There is no ViewData item of type
>   'IEnumerable' that has the key 'DDlist'.', llevo
>   muchoqueriendo saber como se utiliza el DropDownList para almacenar el
>   valor que selecciono en la BDD

Esta es la View

```
<div class="form-group">
            @Html.DropDownList("DDlist","Selecciona Tipo de Producto");
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @*@Html.EditorFor(model => model.IDTipoProducto, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })*@
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.IDTipoProducto, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>
```

y este el Controller

```
        public ActionResult Create()
        {

            List<TipoProductoModel> DDlist = new List<TipoProductoModel>();
            string constring = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ClienteConn"].ToString();
            con = new SqlConnection(constring);
            string sqlquery = "select * from Gral_Tbl_TipoProducto where Activo = 1";
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sqlquery, con);

            con.Open();
            SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            sda.Fill(ds);
            ViewBag.DropDownTipoProducto = ds.Tables[0];

            List<SelectListItem> idproducto = new List<SelectListItem>();


            foreach (System.Data.DataRow dr in ViewBag.DropDownTipoProducto.Rows) 
            {
                idproducto.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = @dr["Nombre"].ToString(), Value = @dr["IDtipoProducto"].ToString() });
            }
            ViewBag.DDlist = idproducto;

            con.Close();
return view();
}
```

este es el post cuando llenas el formulario

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Create( ProductoModel pmodel, FormCollection form)
        {
                try
                {

                pmodel.Nombre = form["Nombre"].ToString();
                pmodel.Descripcion = form["Descripcion"].ToString();
                pmodel.IDTipoProducto = Convert.ToInt32(form["IDTipoProducto"]);

                ClienteDBHanndle pdb = new ClienteDBHanndle();
                    pdb.InsertProduct(pmodel);

                    ViewBag.Message = "Tipo de producto agregado correctamente";
                    ModelState.Clear();



                    return View();
                }
                catch(Exception ex)
                {
                    return View(ex.Message); //asi ves el error de perdido puños
                }
        }
```

Comment: Saludos, bienvenido/a a SOes, te sugiero que veas este workshop de ASP.net MVC, te será de utilidad para ver el panorama del framework: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6LZG76aLykY

Comment: Segun tu descripcion puedes entrar al view "Create", pero el error sucede cuando intentas guardar la informacion. Puedes agregar el codigo del metodo del controller a donde envias el formulario, ya que este es el que te esta dando problemas.

Comment: listo ya lo agregue